# How to get Random number generator to generate two random integers, whose sum is 60, and difference is 14

Tags: java

I have this code, the beginning or my trial.

```
do{ //Do statement, change the rnd number for x and y each time fin is incremented
  x = rnd.nextInt(31);
  y = rnd.nextInt(31);
  z = x+y;

  if(z == 60); // Sum of x and y HAVE to equal sixty.
    {
     System.out.println(x+" "+y);
     fin++;// Just used to increment the fin, just to give my loop an end.
    }
}while(fin!=30)
```

For one, it always prints out two random numbers for x and y. Yet, it NEVER prints out values that equal 60. But my if statement declares, IF z (x+y) equals sixty, then print out x + y. What is my error. Also, how can I use a for loop to generate these values only to have a difference of 14?

Comment: Are you aware that there's only one possible x and y combination that has that property?

Comment: Typo. Remove the semicolon after `if(z == 60);`. That terminates the `if` body. Which means the next block isn't doing what you think.

Comment: Very speedy replies, yes I'm aware there is only on combination. Its not the fact that there is only one, I want to create a simple program to SHOW that this property is true for 23, 37. Does that make sense?

Comment: You want a program to show that 37+23=60 and 37-23=14?

Comment: Ive done it with a do, if statement. Im trying to use a for loop.

Comment: Don't forget complex numbers :-). 37+/-i and 23-/+i

Comment: Note that you are generating two numbers lower than 31. This means they will *never* satisfy the condition, as 37 is not on the [0,31) range.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yeah, I just caught that will looking over it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Thevenin LOL, thanks for the advice bud.

Comment: @Thevenin Why stop there? The [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) will feel left out.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 5):

You need to learn basic algebra:

```
x+y = 60   -> y = 60 - x

x-y = 14   -> x - (60 - x) = 14 
           -> x - 60 + x = 14
           -> 2x -60 = 14
           -> 2x = 74
           -> x = 37

y = 60 - x -> y = 60 - 37
              y = = 23
```

check:

```
23 + 37 = 60
37 - 23  = 14
```

There is literally NO point in running a random number generating loop for this, because there are only TWO numbers that can satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Lol bud, I'm in calculus. I know this, very simple. I was making a program that would SHOW this is true. Its easy to be like... 23 + 37 = 60 with a difference of 14. I'm trying to show the fact that this is true.

Comment: the above is all you'd need. firing random numbers off isn't going to prove anything. there's literally an infinite number of 2-number pairs, and of all that infinity of combinations, 23/37 are the ONLY two that could ever satisfy things. you'd have to test EVERY SINGLE possible pair combo, which is obviously impossible.

Comment: @Dilon -  1) This is algebra, not calculus.  2) You cannot convincingly show it is true by sampling.  The only way to show / prove this numerically (non-algebraically) is by exhaustive search ... and that is impossible because the search space is infinite.

Comment: True enough, I see my flawed logic. Sorry man, wasn't thinking critically about that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have misused the method:

```
Random.nextInt(int n);
```

Actually it returns a random number from 0 to n - 1. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29 for reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to exhaustively prove the valid pairs that will satisfy your conditions, you can use a single `for` loop from `0` to `60` and something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 60; x++) {
        int y = 60 - x;
        int max = Math.max(x, y);
        int min = Math.min(x, y);
        if (max - min == 14) {
            System.out.printf("%d, %d%n", x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Which output(s) the only valid (and mirrored) pair

```
23, 37
37, 23
```

Comment: But this approach fails if there is no integer solution.

Comment: @StephenC How does it fail? It produces no output if there is no solution. It's still better then generating two random integers and testing only one of the conditions.

Comment: What if the solution had been a fraction?

Comment: OP's title specifies integers. It's two inequalities. The constraints are very basic.